# Proving the Jacobi's Identity: $\det A^{-1}[\alpha^c,\beta^c ] = (-1)^{p(\alpha,\beta)} \frac{\det A[\beta,\alpha]}{\det A}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification

I'm reading Matrix Analysis by Horn & Johnson and have bit of trouble proving what they called the *Jacobi's identity* :

> $$ \det A^{-1}[\alpha^c,\beta^c ] = (-1)^{p(\alpha,\beta)} \frac{\det A[\beta,\alpha]}{\det A} $$
> with $\displaystyle p(\alpha,\beta) = \sum_{i\in \alpha} i + \sum_{j\in \beta} j$ , where nonsingular $A\in M_n(F) , $ $A^{-1}[\alpha^c,\beta^c]$ denotes an $|\alpha^c| \times |\beta^c| $ submatrix of $A^{-1}$ which contains rows of $A^{-1}$ indexed by $\alpha^c$ and columns of $A^{-1}$ indexed by $\beta^c$ .

Actually I think $|\alpha| = |\beta| \le n  $ otherwise the determinant is undefined . And $\alpha , \beta \subseteq \{1,..,n\}$ .

P.S.: I did a bit of websearch and found out there're Jacobi's identity , Jacobi's formula but they don't really look the same as this one here .

---

**Attempt :**

By $adj(A)A = \det(A)I$. We have
$$
 A^{-1} = \frac{adj(A)}{\det(A)}
$$
so
$$
 A^{-1}[\alpha^c,\beta^c ] = \frac{adj(A)[\alpha^c,\beta^c ] }{\det(A)}
$$
$adj(A)[\alpha^c,\beta^c ]$ only contains all $(i,j)-$ cofactors of A with $i \in \beta^c ,  j \in \alpha^c    $ . At the same time $A[\beta^c , \alpha^c ]$ can only produce all the aforementioned cofactors .  So  I guess
$$
 A^{-1}[\alpha^c,\beta^c ]   = \frac{adj(A[\beta^c , \alpha^c ]) }{\det(A)}
$$
by $\det(adj(A)) = (\det(A))^{n-1}$
$$
 \det A^{-1}[\alpha^c,\beta^c ]   = \frac{(\det A[\beta^c , \alpha^c ])^{ n-|\alpha| -  1} }{(\det(A))^n}
$$
But I cannot proceed , am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is merely a restatement of the determinant formula for block matrices. Consider the case where $\alpha=\beta=\{1,2,\ldots,k\}$ and the elements of $A$ are $n^2$ algebraically independent indeterminates. Let
$$
A=\pmatrix{X_{k\times k}&Y\\ Z&W}
$$
Then
$$
\pmatrix{I&0\\ -ZX^{-1}&I}\pmatrix{X&Y\\ Z&W}\pmatrix{I&-X^{-1}Y\\ 0&I}
=\pmatrix{X&0\\ 0&S}
$$
where $S=W-ZX^{-1}Y$ is known as the [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement) of $X$ in $A$. It follows that
$$
\det(A)=\det(X)\det(S)
$$
and
$$
A^{-1}
=\pmatrix{I&X^{-1}Y\\ 0&I}\pmatrix{X^{-1}&0\\ 0&S^{-1}}\pmatrix{I&0\\ ZX^{-1}&I}
=\pmatrix{\ast&\ast\\ \ast&S^{-1}}.
$$
Therefore $\det(A^{-1}[\alpha^c,\beta^c])=\det(S^{-1})=\frac{\det(X)}{\det(A)}=\frac{\det(A[\beta,\alpha])}{\det(A)}$. Since the LHS is identical to the RHS when the entries of $A$ are indeterminates, the identity also holds when the elements of $A$ are numbers. Now the general case follows by a permutation of the rows and columns of $A$.